# PHP create file from byte array from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, file, arrays, recreate

I have a mysql dtabase which contains a `byte[]` from a file in a `BLOB`.
Now I want to read the byte array from the database and output the file.
So:

1. How can I get a `byte[]` from mysql in PHP and
2. How can I output a file from a `byte[]` in PHP?

Comment: And do I need to add any header data for different file formats?

Comment: Please help me! I really need help with this

Comment: Did you solve it in the meantime?